# Differentiation: chain rule over multiple arguments

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I am wondering whether the following generally holds:

$$ \frac{ \delta f(g(x), h(x))} {\delta x} = \frac{ \delta f(g(x), h(x))} {\delta g(x)} *\frac{ \delta g(x)} {\delta x} + \frac{ \delta f(g(x), h(x))} {\delta h(x)} *\frac{ \delta h(x)} {\delta x} $$

If so, what is the name of this rule, or of which existing rule is it a special case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is the [chain rule for multivariable calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

If you put $p(x) = (g(x),h(x))$, you can write the multivariable chain rule as
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \nabla f(p) \cdot p'(x)$$
to more closely resemble the one-variable chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in general. For $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m, x\mapsto f(x)$ and $g:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^l, y\mapsto g(y)$ You have
$$\frac\partial{\partial x_j} g\circ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac\partial{\partial y_k} g(f(x)) \cdot \frac\partial{\partial x_j} f_k(x)$$